Laravel filament file upload with custom action or upload files in Google Drive using file upload and get files and view separate page
Upload files in Google Drive in laravel filament and then get files from Google Drive and display them in an iframe. Is this possible or not?
I want to upload multiple files upload in Google Drive using Laravel Filament fileupload form builder method. also get those all the files from Google Drive and display them in Iframe.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
